# __RemoteAppManagementInfo__ SharePoint 2013 - remote hosting service is not configured

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am seeing an odd error deploying a simple Hello World app on my new **SharePoint 2013** server using **Visual Studio 2012**.  The error is "*The remote hosting service is not configured*" and the internal message and stack trace are:

> Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.Server.SecureStoreServiceTargetApplicationNotFoundException: Target application not found (application id: __RemoteAppManagementInfo__).
>          at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecureStoreHelper.ExecuteSecureStoreMethod(String methodName, Object[] args)
>          at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.AppDeployment.RemoteWebSiteAccount.Initialize()
>          at Microsoft.SharePoint.Packaging.SPRemoteWebSiteDeploymentGroup.ConfigureClientAndAccount()
>          at Microsoft.SharePoint.Packaging.SPRemoteWebSiteDeploymentGroup.DeployInternal()
>          at Microsoft.SharePoint.Packaging.SPRemoteWebSiteDeploymentGroup.Deploy()
>          at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAppTask.DeployOperation()
>          at Microsoft.SharePoint.Lifecycle.MonitoredTaskExecution.DoTask()

I know that I could probably go into the **Secure Store Service** and configure a new secure store target application with that application ID, but I did not see this in any of the setup documentation, and I really would like to know where that is coming from.  I feel like I'm missing a simple configuration setting somewhere, but I cannot find it.

Comment: There seems to be [(4) claim parameters required for the Secure Store application \__RemoteAppManagementInfo__](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/9adf7c77-eb38-4a3d-a11e-5d8f9615b3ed/) - Username, Passsword, ManagementEndpoint, and IsEnabled. I'm not sure what goes in the URL - did you succeed in resolving this issue? [This MSDN sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Sharepoint-2013-Autohosted-8c8d4840) states that "*Autohosted apps in SharePoint 2013 can be installed only on SharePoint Online websites*". Is this not a privately available feature?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are creating **Autohosted** app.

**Autohosted apps** are only supported with **Office 365 SharePoint Online**. 
This may remain true for some time after the release of **SharePoint 2013**.

Comment: You seem to have nailed this issue - [**Auto-hosting** uses Azure Websites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179887.aspx#SP15_app_HostingOptions) which obviously wouldn't work on-premise *yet*. **Provider-hosted** would require you to create your own website/DB infrastructure, while **SharePoint-Hosted** is definitely the route to take.

Comment: Depends on the actual application requirements. SharePoint-Hosted apps are having a lot of limitations (no Remote Event receivers, no C# code)

Comment: To get around the limitations - do you just need to manually create and deploy a SP solution? Is there no easy way to deploy a Sharepoint application (*say WCF app*) that contains c# server code? Does this just mean I need to be an admin on the SP server to create IIS sites/virtual directories?

Comment: You can still create SP Farm solutions for SharePoint 2013. If you are after this new app model there are only three options: auto-hosted and provider-hosted (both support server side code, which is run in a separate site (Azure and on-premise) and SharePoint-hosted (no C#/VB code allowed)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - [this MSDN video also helped fill in the blanks for farm solutions vs. hosted apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apps/fp123626.aspx) - **Module 1.1 → 1.2**. [This MSDN link will help you choose which Sharepoint API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj164060.aspx) you should use.